# CSS Drop Down Menu not working in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have tried all most all solutions available, for displaying the drop down menus in IE6 on hover but cudnt.It works fine in other version of IE but not with IE6.The block for sub menus is not getting displayed.
Below is the html code and css code.Pls Help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
<link href="styles23.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='home.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>  
<li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>DNS</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>LP </span></a></li>
<li><a href="#.htm"><span>PC</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Careers</span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'><span>Selection Process</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Submit Resume</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS Code as follows

```
#cssmenu {
border: none;
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font: 40.5% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
width: Auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
background: #ffb200;
height: 25px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:740px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 16px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }
#cssmenu li {
float: left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
#cssmenu li a {
color: #000;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;/*for changing menu font*/
line-height: 25px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 15px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:11px;
}
#cssmenu li a:hover {
background: #003597;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover a {
background: #003597;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu li ul {
display: none;
height: 30px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: 150px;
z-index: 100;
}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
#cssmenu li li {
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 240px; 
height:33px; 
background: #FBDC7F;
}
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
background: none;
}
#cssmenu li ul a {
display: block;
height: 25px;
font-size: 10px;
font-style: normal;
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu li ul a:hover,
#cssmenu li ul li:hover a {
border: 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
height:23px; /*changing the sub menu hover height*/
text-decoration:none;
background: #003597;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a
{
display: block;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You're using a whole stack of CSS features that don't work in IE6. Specifically the main issue is the `li:hover`. If you really need to support IE6, then you won't be able to achieve this in pure CSS -- it is not possible to get this to work in IE6 without some Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
   display: block;
}
```

The `:hover` statement works only on `a`-Elements in IE6.

What you could do, is a small JavaScript which gives the css-class `.hover` to the `li`-Element on the JavaScript-Event `onmouseover` and removes it on `onmouseout`.

Your declaration would then look like this:

```
#cssmenu li.hover ul
```

Comment: @spaark Can u pls elaborate it, Im confused.Is that u r saying to write a javascript function which on mouse-over on li will display the block.Pls let me knw with an example.

Comment: I think i got it..its like on mouse over evnt i shud add the class                                          document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass"; and on mouseout remove.Thank you spaark

Comment: Yeah, or you could use `<li onmouseover="this.className='hover'" onmouseout="this.className=''">Text</li>`.

Comment: You could mark as aswered if you got the answer you were looking for :-)